# Perhaps a TV airing

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. 1970s blockbuster's 1 down villain (4)
>   3. Original 1 down's candy store emptied between the 1st of November and the 3rd of January (7)
>   6. Superior to 1 down, among others, is lost on the battlefield (3, abbr.)
>   7. 1 down actor from space making comeback with energy (5)
>   8. Special respect for 1 down's enemy (7)
>   10. A bit of salt with fish – new way to prepare American speciality? (6)
>   12. Sheep covered by Homer in *Odyssey* (6)
>   17. Resort to hiring tools for 1 down, perhaps (13)
>   19. Crime lord holding key successor of 7 across, briefly (6)
>   23. Obstruct running my site (6)
>   25. *(See 29)*
>   27. City in Brazil in possession of commercial electronic equipment (5)
>   29/25. 1 down creator's men failing horribly (3,7)
>   30. 19 across's successor's siblings standing by grandmother (7)
>   31. Hideous beast in Rome? For that reason, looking back (4)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Spy's bones broken after troublesome situation occurred, finally (5,4)
>   2. Which person is possessed by know-how? (3)
>   3. Jonesy's partner and Native Americans dropped in… (3)
>   4. …more agreeable French city, north of Rouen (5)
>   5. Perhaps a TV airing of 1 down is central to clearer understanding (5)
>   6. Just no money for expensive textile (4)
>   9. A woman's geographical chart upside down (3)
>   11. Dissolve and reveal unnatural, twisted secrets (5)
>   13. 7 across crossing rivers from the south, leading to sense of self-importance (3)
>   14. "I am holding Ronnie", James is saying (5)
>   15. Skip introductions to go in at them – love in motion (2,3,4)
>   16. 1 down production company, for a very long time (3)
>   18. A couple involved in networking (3)
>   20. Some fashionable restaurant to be having more capacity (5)
>   21. Multiplied by 1000 in relationships (5)
>   22. Sister in cotton underwear (3)
>   24. Ripped actor named Rip (4)
>   26. Liquor finally kicking in (3)
>   28. Like a body part not shown in party (3)

Comment: Almost done, but I have to compliment you on 17a.  Spectacular clue.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Thanks! I wad pretty happy how many "themed" answers fit in the grid, even though I had to leave out the most recent entry on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete grid is behind the spoilertag. Thanks to @Stiv and @Tom for help with the last few clues. Full disclosure: I did have to do some Googling since I don't know much about [that thing clued by 1 down].

(Should I provide detailed explanations for all the solved clues?)

Favourite clue: 21 down. Honourable mention to 12 across for the nice surface.

> [image]

Comment: 3 more for you: rot13(6q ZRER (pnfuzrer-pnfu) 11q NAAHY (qvffbyir, onpxjneqf va gur grkg) 15q BA GUR ZBIR (jbeqf jvgubhg svefg yrggref))

Comment: 10a rot13(funxra - f + unxr + a). 28d rot13(qvt - (fuva)qvt). 31a rot13(bter - retb<).

Comment: I've got full parsing for everything but 3a.  Partial Parsing: P naq L vafgrnq bs PNAQL,  AA sebz gur ynfg ovg.  Pna'g trg gur BRE sebz "Fgber Rzcgvrq"

Comment: @Chris - maybe 3a is con(fectio)nery, removing between the two n's.